# String.split() will keep original char array inside

Tags: java, string, split, substring, deep-copy

I've noticed that Java String will reuse char array inside it to avoid creating new char array for a new String instance in method such as subString(). There are several unpublish constructors in String for this purpose, accepting a char array and two int as range to construct a String instance.

But until today I found that split will also reuse the char arr of original String instance. Now I read a loooooong line from a file, split it with ","  and cut a very limit column for real usage. Because every part of the line secretly holding the reference of the looooong char array, I got an OOO very soon.

here is example code:

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(3000000);
BufferedReader origReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
        "G:\\filewithlongline.txt")));
String line = origReader.readLine();
int i = 0;
while ((line = origReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String name = line.split(',')[0];
    test.add(name);
    i++;
    if (i % 100000 == 0) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
System.out.println(test.size());
```

Is there any standard method in JDK to make sure that every String instance that spitted is a "real deep copy" not "shallow copy"?

Now I am using a very ugly workaround to force creating a new String instance:

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(3000000);
BufferedReader origReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
        "G:\\filewithlongline.txt")));
String line = origReader.readLine();
int i = 0;
while ((line = origReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String name = line.split(',')[0]+"  ".trim(); // force creating a String instance
    test.add(name);
    i++;
    if (i % 100000 == 0) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
System.out.println(test.size());
```

Comment: I really really wonder what OOO is

Comment: @SerkanArıkuşu OOO here means Out Of Memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is to create a new String directly. This is one of the rare cases where its a good idea.

```
String name = new String(line.split(",")[0]); // note the use of ","
```

An alternative is to parse the file yourself.

```
do {
    StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
    int ch;
    while((ch = origReader.read()) >= 0 && ch != ',' && ch >= ' ') {
       name.append((char) ch);
    }
    test.add(name.toString());
} while(origReader.readLine() != null);
```

Comment: Finally I found the reason why String has a constructor which accept another String instance as paramter :-).  So, it is needed to iterator the String array from split() and call new String() for columns needed. Is there a "deepSplit()"?

Comment: I'm perplexed by that loop you're using... once `origReader.read` returns `-1` and the inner loop exits, then surely `origReader.readLine` will then have to return `null`.

Comment: @veer If the inner loop stops in the outer loop will as well. This would only occur if the last line doesn't have a , or a new line.

Comment: @PeterLawrey well the output will be invalid, as you're calling `StringBuilder.append(int)`. Aside from that, I see neither where you're checking for `,` and I still don't understand the logic behind the two loops.

Comment: @veer if there is an end of file before a ',' the whole line will be used.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I understood that, but your code (before you just edited a minute ago) did not do that. Besides, the OP does not specify it should do that :-p

Comment: @veer That's what it does in the original example. But you are right it needed to check for `,`

Comment: @PeterLawrey new String() sounds like a good way to go. It is more simple than parse it myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`String` has a [copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28java.lang.String%29) you can use for this purpose.

```
final String name = new String(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(',')));
```

... or, as Peter suggested, just only read until the `,`.

```
final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
do {
  int ch;
  while ((ch = origReader.read()) >= 0 && ch != ',') {
    buf.append((char) ch);
  }
  test.add(buf.toString());
  buf.setLength(0);
} while (origReader.readLine() != null);
```